# Circular button with image and circular progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to make a button with an image inside and a circular progress bar on the outside, that is colored after pressing the button.

I have an .svg image that must be displayed in a circle with a diameter of 140px. This image must be a button that triggers a request and activate the progress bar on its circumference.

I'm looking for a simple example without using elaborate libraries (at most jquery).

I tried with a svg in the html but I don't know how to turn it into a button and activate the progress bar, or clean it. Also I can't size it properly.

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <image x="0%" y="0%" width="140" height="140" xlink:href="images/small-gate.svg"></image>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="#428bca" stroke-width="6" fill="url(#image)" />
</svg>
```

I would like to create something like example, but instead of the "pause" (two dashes) I would like my .svg image.

example:

[image]

Comment: I guess you have to change the ref on the image element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a barebones approach:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", addImgButton);
function addImgButton(){
  var element = document.getElementById("mybutton");
      element.addEventListener("click", toggleAnim);  
}

function toggleAnim(){
  var element = document.getElementById("pbar");
      element.classList.toggle("showAnim");
}
```

```css
:root{
  --perc: 65;
  --sw: 6;
  --atime: 2s;
  --pi2: 6.28318;
  --r: 40;
  --perim: calc(var(--pi2) * var(--r));
  --pend: calc(var(--r) * var(--pi2) * var(--perc) / 100);
  --prest: calc(var(--r) * var(--pi2) * (100 - var(--perc)) / 100);
}
#progress{
  stroke: #aaa; /* #428bca; */
  stroke-width: var(--sw);
}
#pbar{
  stroke-width: var(--sw);
  fill: none;
}

.showAnim{
  stroke: #428bca;
  stroke-dasharray: var(--pend) var(--prest);
  animation: progress var(--atime) ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 1000;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cFrame">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
    <image id="mybutton" x="0" y="0%" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Melithreptus_lunatus.jpg" clip-path="url(#cFrame)"></image>
    <circle id="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="url(#image)" />
  <circle id="pbar" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
```

It uses a CSS animation and plain javascript for triggering. The simple idea behind animated progress is that you can use the `stroke-dasharray` property to show an arc. The only trick is to properly set the start and end values.
Regarding the inner image, it should be pretty simple: you set the coordinates and proportions of the picture (I also added a clipping to only show it inside the circle) and use its `id` or `class` to add a `click` event listener. A couple of points:

- You can customize the progress at the beginning of the `css` section. The variable `--perc` contains the final percentage of the arc. The variable `--atime` controls the animation time. The variable `--r` is also important. It contains the radius of the circle, if you change it in the svg you also need to change it here.
- The javascript code toggles the `showAnim` class for the `pbar` circle in response to a click on the image.
- The starting `stroke-dasharray` for `pbar` is `0 1000`. The second value is simply larger than the length of the arc. When I tried to set it with a variable, the animation did not work. If you increase the radius of the circle, you may need to increase that second value.
- You can play around with the example in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/mohingudino/pen/LYEjeXm).